# How to share one row of a Google Sheet with a user?

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking to share a Google Sheet with 150 users in a way where every person can only edit one row.

I know how to do this manually, using set permissions, but I was wondering if there was a quicker way to accomplish this task. I have column in my spreadsheet with every users email.

I know Professors do this when they share one row of a gradebook in Google Sheets with a student.

I appreciate the help!

**edit*** one caveat I should add is that the cells must be editable with the user they are shared with.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is, there is a Google sheet with some data, individual rows of which has to be shared with people.

1. Suppose I have this sheet "StudentList" with tab "Sheet1", which contains 2 cells Name and RollNo
2. Now open a separate sheet "Copy StudentList", Now type the following:
   =IMPORTRANGE("link of StudentList","TabName!cellFrom:cellTo")
   I have kept the snapshots. I hope it helps.[image]